# uninitialized value $4 in string eq - Perl

Tags: xml, regex, perl

```
@files = glob "*.xml";

undef $/;
for $file (@files) {
    $indent = 0;
    open FILE, $file or die "Couldn't open $file for reading: $!";
    $_ = readline *FILE;
    close FILE or die "Couldn't close $file: $!";

    # Remove whitespace between > and < if that is the only thing separating them
    s/(?<=>)\s+(?=<)//g;

    # Indent
    s{  # Capture a tag <$1$2$3>,
        # a potential closing slash $1
        # the contents $2
        # a potential closing slash $3
        <(/?)([^/>]+)(/?)> 

        # Optional white space
        \s*

        # Optional tag.
        # $4 contains either undef, "<" or "</"
        (?=(</?))?
    }
    {
        # Adjust the indentation level.
        # $3: A <foo/> tag. No alteration to indentation.
        # $1: A closing </foo> tag. Drop one indentation level
        # else: An opening <foo> tag. Increase one indentation level
        $indent +=
            $3 ?  0 :
            $1 ? -1 :
                  1;

        # Put the captured tag back into place
        "<$1$2$3>" .
        # Two closing tags in a row. Add a newline and indent the next line
        ($1 and ($4 eq "</") ?
            "\n" . ("  " x $indent) : 
        # This isn't a closing tag but the next tag is. Add a newline and
        # indent the next line.
        $4 ?
            "\n" . ("  " x $indent) :
        # This isn't a closing tag - no special indentation. I forget why
        # this works.
            ""
        )
    # /g repeat as necessary
    # /e Execute the block of perl code to create replacement text
    # /x Allow whitespace and comments in the regex
    }gex;

    open FILE, ">", $file or die "Couldn't open $file for writing: $!";
    print FILE or die "Couldn't write to $file: $!";
    close FILE or die "Couldn't close $file: $!";
}
```

I'm using this code to indent a bunch of xml files correctly. However, when I execute I get:

```
Use of uninitialized value $4 in string eq at C:/Users/souzamor/workspace/Parser/xmlreformat.pl line 25.
```

and `line 25` is:

```
# $4 contains either undef, "<" or "</"
```

I don't know why is it, and I'm new to `Perl`. Could someone please help me?

Comment: You must have you line numbers off, the error appears to come from the line `($1 and ($4 eq "</") ?`.

Comment: I'm using `Perl- 5.10.1`

Comment: Obligatory:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/9719

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `$4` refers to the fourth capturing parenthesis in your regular expression, in this case: `(?=(</?))?`. As the comment states this may be undefined because of the `?` at the very end which means "this thing may be there, but it also might not be".

If you use an undefined value (signalled via the special value `undef` in Perl) in certain ways, including in a string comparison with `eq`, you get a warning from Perl. You can easily check whether or not a variable is defined with `defined($var)`.

In your particular case `$4` is used in this phrase:

```
($1 and ($4 eq "</") ? "\n" . ("  " x $indent) : 
 $4                  ? "\n" . ("  " x $indent) :
                       ""
```

Fixing the warning is as easy as replacing those tests with this:

```
($1 and defined($4) and ($4 eq "</") ? "\n" . ("  " x $indent) : 
$4                                   ? "\n" . ("  " x $indent) :
                                       ""
```

Note that you don't have to check for `defined($4)` in the second line in this particular case, but it wouldn't hurt either.

Comment: Almost there ...  now it does not like `<(/?)([^/>]+)(/?)> `

Comment: Download an XML pretty-printer form CPAN. save yourself the heartache of trying to parse XML without the benefit of a parser.

Comment: @LenJaffe Could you give me more details?

Answer (score 0):

Unless there's no final match there:

```
(?=(</?))?
```

If that final question mark allows the match to proceed to replacement, then `$4` will be `undef`. For example (using Perl 5.10 or better, for older it should be safe to use `||` instead of `//`):

```
(($4 // '') eq "</")
```

You'll just have to guard against that or turn off the warnings. You can't move the capture outside the zero-width look ahead because that will always set `$4` to an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

So this run-time error, is telling you that given your current input, $4 has no value, but you're accessing it anyway.

So the lines:

```
 # Optional tag.
 # $4 contains either undef, "<" or "</"
```

Are lying. If $4 was undef, you'd be getting a complaint about an undefined value rather than an uninitialized value.

$4 is not matching anything at the time you execute this s{}{} statement.

Unless you MUST write an XML pretty-printer, you should get one from the CPAN.

Answer (score -2):

If it is works correctly then you could ignore warnings. Change this line

```
close FILE or die "Couldn't close $file: $!";
```

to

```
 close FILE or die "Couldn't close $file: $!";
 no warnings 'uninitalized';
```

But it would better/nicer to use some xml parser library to parse xml...

Regards,

Comment: I have tried so many, but all of the failed due to some random problem.